# If $R\subset S$, does it necessarily follow that $R[G]\subset S[G]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-rings

So perhaps this is a trivial question, but suppose we have some rings (possibly noncommutative) such that $R\subset S$, and a group (possibly infinite) $G$, does it necessarily follow that $R[G]\subset S[G]$?

Comment: By definition, an sum of terms of the form $rg$ with $r\in R$ and $g\in G$ is also a sum of terms of the form $sg$ with $s\in S$ and $g\in G$.

Answer (score 2):

It will be contained clearly. I guess you are asking will it be a subring.

So, yes it will be, as let $\alpha =\sum a_gg\ , \beta=\sum b_gg \in RG$ then $\alpha-\beta=\sum(a_g-b_g)g\in RG$ as $(a_g-b_g)\in R$ and also it is closed under multiplication as $\alpha\beta=\sum_{g,h\in  G} a_gb_hgh$ as again $R$ is closed under multiplication so $a_gb_h\in R$